# Get Ext JS version

Tags: extjs

I have taken over a PHP + Ext JS project. Unfortunately, there is no documentation. How do I find out the Ext JS version that is being used?

In jQuery, we get the version by running `$().jquery;`. Anything like this in Ext JS?

Comment: How come I was able to find it just by looking at the Ext JS source code in half a minute? Or by *looking* at the Ext JS documentation?

Comment: @Chris Morgan because you're a god

Answer (score 33):

Two easy ways to do this. First is from a web browser's console..

In ExtJS 3.x:

`Ext.version;`

In ExtJS 4.0:

`Ext.getVersion('extjs');`

In >= ExtJS 4.1

`Ext.getVersion().version;`

Or you can look in the ext-all-debug.js and check the version number at the top of the script. In all versions dating back to 1.0 they include the version number at the top of the ext-all-debug script, it might be called something else but just have a look around your application hierarchy.

Comment: In ExtJS 4.2.1 `Ext.version` returns undefined

Answer (score 5):

Since ExtJS 4.1.1:

```
Ext.getVersion().version;
```

Comment: See my other comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607205/get-extjs-version#comment25334157_6607315

Comment: `Ext.getVersion().version` also work with current version 6.5.3

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.Version-method-getVersion

```
var ver = Ext.getVersion('core');
            if (ver.isLessThan('4.0.1')) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                   title: 'Err',
                   msg: 'Old version',
                   buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                   icon: Ext.Msg.ERROR
               });
```

Comment: This is specific to Ext 4, which is unlikely in use in his legacy project. Useful for future legacy projects though ;)

Comment: Second [bmoeskau's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607205/get-extjs-version#comment7806748_6607315), this answer is pretty ridiculous.  The API linked to in the answer clearly states Ext.getVersion() is not available until version 4.0.0!

Answer (score 1):

put this in javascript function.

```
            var majorVersion;
        var fullVersion;
        if (Ext.version != undefined) {
            majorVersion = Ext.version.substring(0, Ext.version.indexOf("."));
            fullVersion = Ext.version;
        } else {
            majorVersion = Ext.getVersion().getMajor();
            fullVersion = Ext.getVersion().version;
        }
        alert("Ext version:"+majorVersion+" "+fullVersion);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code fetch ext js version

```
Ext.versions.extjs.version
```

Actualy `Ext.versions` global variable contains many version.

It also contain browser version like Chrome.

Variable name is `Ext.versions` not `Ext.version`

Thank you. I hope it might help you.