# How to know the version of sencha from the code

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I got an existing old application and I am trying to customize the same. Since it is an old application built in Ext JS/Sencha, the version of Ext js i see from my web console is 1.1.1.

Ext.version gives 1.1.1 as the result. So how will i know which version of sencha it is ? like sencha 2.3.1 is the latest.

I am new to sencha and hence i am not sure about how to check the version and also how the Ext js version is related to sencha version.

I hope the latest Extjs version is 4.x series and sencha is 2.3.1.

So for my existing application , Ext js version is 1.1.1 and i need to know the sencha version of the same.

Please help.

Comment: Why are you looking to know the compatible sencha touch version of your desktop application (Extjs)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get ExtJS version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607205/get-extjs-version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sencha is the company behind ExtJS and Sencha Touch. There is no version number for sencha.

If you are working with ExtJS (the desktop framework) the latest version is 4.2.2 and for Sencha Touch (the mobile version of the framework) the latest version is 2.3.1.

The latest version numbers are availible here: http://docs.sencha.com

```
Ext.version
```

is always the right attempt to get the version number, no matter if Sencha touch or ExtJS.

Answer (score 0):

For the core you can try the following from the JS console:
Ext.versions.core.version

For other components just replace the word "core" in the previous command with the component name. e.g to get the "extjs" version you would type :
Ext.versions.extjs.version