# Version of Ext JS used by AEM 6.5

Tags: extjs, aem, aem-6

Which version of Ext JS library does AEM 6.5 use?

I have already tried to find the version by using the solutions described in the answers to the following questions, but none of them worked in my case:

- [Version of Ext JS used by AEM 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553557/version-of-ext-js-used-by-aem-6-1)
- [Get Ext JS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6607205/get-ext-js-version)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following version of Ext JS in the file "/libs/cq/ui/widgets.js" of my AEM 6.5 instance:
3.4.0